# Unable to authenticate against azure fhir api from msal-react

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal.js, msal-react, fhir-server-for-azure, azure-health-data-services

I am trying to access the azure api for fhir from a react application. I am using msal-react 2.x. I get a 401 error when I try to access the "/Patient" rest endpoint. I have created a Azure AD application (SPA). The app has FHIR Data Reader access to the fhir api service. Api permissions are
Azure Healthcare Apis (patient.all.read, user_impersonation).
Graph (User.Read, profile, openid).
CORS is enabled on the FHIR api.

React code.
index.js

```
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <App />
      </MsalProvider>
```

App.js

```
    <MsalAuthenticationTemplate
      interactionType={InteractionType.Popup}
      authenticationRequest={authRequest}
      errorComponent={ErrorComponent}
      loadingComponent={LoadingComponent}
    >
      <App />
    </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
```

msalConfig.js

```
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "{clientid}",
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}',
    },
};

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export const authRequest = {
    scopes: [
        "https://{myserver}.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default"
    ]
};

export const acquireAccessToken = async () => {
    const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount(); 
    const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

    const request = {
        scopes: [
            "https://{myserver}.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default"
        ],
        account: activeAccount || accounts[0]
    };

    const authResult = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);

    return authResult.accessToken    
};
```

I am probably missing something with the scopes.

Decoded token attached[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @Wlada no this is unresolved. Looks to be related to Azure permissions needed for the Azure AD SPA app to the Fhir Api service.

Answer (score 1):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I tried to access the "/Patient" rest endpoint with token generated with **`User.Read`** scope, I too got **401 Unauthorized** error as below:

```
GET https://demofhir20.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

**Response:**

[image]

> The error  **`401 Unauthorized`**  usually occurs if you make calls to the Azure Healthcare API with  **invalid**  audience(Microsoft Graph).

To **confirm** that, you can decode the access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass *only* **Azure Healthcare API** in `scope` parameter while generating access token.

In my case, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow via Postman with below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: <appID>
scope: https://demofhir20.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

To check **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims, you can decode above token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website:

[image]

When I used this token to access the "/Patient" rest endpoint, I got **response** successfully as below:

```
GET https://demofhir20.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your code, remove all **Microsoft Graph** permissions like User.Read, openid, profile from `scope` parameter and pass only  **Azure Healthcare API**  scope like this:

```js
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "{clientid}",
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}',
    },
};

export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

export const authRequest = {
    scopes: [
        "https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default"
    ]
};

export const acquireAccessToken = async () => {
    const activeAccount = msalInstance.getActiveAccount(); 
    const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();

    const request = {
        scopes: [
            "https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/user_impersonation",
            "https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/patient.all.read",
        ],
        account: activeAccount || accounts[0]
    };

    const authResult = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request);

    return authResult.accessToken    
};
```

If you are generating **access token** by authenticating as user, make sure to assign **`FHIR Data Reader`** role to user account under FHIR API service like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm still getting a 401. Once  thing I noticed though is in the token the aud is "https://fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com" and not "https://{myfhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com".

Comment: Could you include the decoded token claims by editing your question?

Comment: You need to pass scope as `https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default` not `https://fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/user_impersonation` or `https://fhir.azurehealthcareapis.com/patient.all.read`

Comment: There are 2 requests, one on login and one of azquiretoken. I pass https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default to both. Still get 401. I will post the decoded claims shortly

Comment: Token is valid, can you try calling `GET https://{your_fhir}.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient` in Postman by including that token and add that snip in your question?

Comment: Using that token in postman doesnt work either. The azure ad app that is created is for a SPA. The fhir api documentation is outdated and shows app registration using the implicit flow which is no longer recommended. I guess the issue is with calling from React using the auth code flow. If I use client id and secret from postman it is successful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255348/discussion-between-sridevi-and-webdevbing).